# Run two network call in parallel (synchronous) and get their result to compare before moving to next code in flutter mobile

Tags: api, flutter, dart

Fallowing code include two Network Request which is running Asynchronous, I want to run them parallel and get their result to compare before moving to next code.

```
 final failureOrGovernate = await getGovernateDataUsecase();
  
 final failureOrArea = await getAreaDataUsecase();
```

Thank You, your comments and answers are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can wait on multiple futures in parallel with Future.wait()

```
final both = await Future.wait([getGovernateDataUsecase(), getAreaDataUsecase()]);

final failureOrGovernate = both[0];
final failureOrArea = both[1];
```